# Show that equations system has only one solution

Tags: systems-of-equations, determinant

Show that the equation system has only one solution

$$ax+by+cz=d_1\\cx+ay+bz=d_2\\x+y+z=d_3$$

Where a, b, c are real number that are not all the same, $d_1,\ d_2,\ d_3$ are any real numbers.

I get the $$det(A)=a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc$$

How do you show $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc\ne 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing your work, notice that $$2a^2 + 2b^2 + 2c^2 - 2ab - 2ac - 2bc = (a - b)^2 + (a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2.$$
If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are not all the same, then the value above must be positive.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you